# Spring LDAP Samples

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security

Am using A java web application using springs. i need to authenticate the users before logging in to my application. And i need to use LDAP. I googled it and not getting a proper sample to follow. since am new to java am not able to go through complete 1 cycle of the code. below is the sample config file i got. but where to use that and how to use that? i got my ADS details from the software by name ADExplorer. Can anyone please guide me for a continuous flow of how to do this?

```
// LDAP config
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = '10010101'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword ='Temppass@123'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://DOMAIN.com:3268/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true // typically needed for Active Directory
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'DC=DOMAIN,DC=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="sAMAccountName={0}" // for Active Directory you need this
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['mail', 'displayName','employeeID'] // extra attributes you want returned; see below for custom classes that access this data
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider'] // specify this when you want to skip attempting to load from db and only use LDAP

// role-specific LDAP config grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = false 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false

grails.plugin.quartz2.autoStartup = true
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349628/ldap-authentication/12349733#12349733
You can check the above link.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using grails, you can use [ldap plugin](http://www.grails.org/LDAP+Plugin)